# Text Responsive in Carousel (Bootstrap 4)l

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using this code above to do a carousel with a text inside. When I decrease the screen or open the website in a smartphone, the text is all misaligned. Someone knows what I need to do? I've looked for a lot of website examples, but I didn't find a good answer for this problem.

For instance, if the text is like this:

WELCOME TO MY SITE
I'm glad you came

When I resize or open in the cellphone, the text is something like it:

WE

L

C

OM

E

TO

MY

S

ITE

(...)

**The HTML code is quite similar to the example of Bootstrap 4 official site:**

```css
/* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
    -------------------------------------------------- */
    
    /* Carousel base class */
    .carousel {
      margin-bottom: 4rem;
    }
    /* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
    .carousel-caption {
      z-index: 10;
      bottom: 3rem;
    }
    
    /* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
    .carousel-item {
      height: 32rem;
      background-color: #777;
    }
    .carousel-item > img {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      min-width: 100%;
      height: 32rem;
    }
    
    
    
    
    /* RESPONSIVE CSS
    -------------------------------------------------- */
    
    @media (min-width: 40em) {
      /* Bump up size of carousel content */
      .carousel-caption p {
        margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
        font-size: 1.25rem;
        line-height: 1.4;
      }
    
      .featurette-heading {
        font-size: 50px;
      }
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 62em) {
      .featurette-heading {
        margin-top: 7rem;
      }
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="first-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="First slide">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block text-left">
              <h1>Example headline.</h1>
              <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="second-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Second slide">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block">
              <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
              <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="third-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Third slide">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block text-right">
              <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
              <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Misaligned in what sense? Are you wanting the text vertically centered in the carousel?

Comment: I've edited the post to show you an example

Comment: What viewport width are you see it displayed like that? I have the viewport at 250 and it's display reasonably well. You can view it [here](https://www.codeply.com/go/kMbOJLxDGG) and adjust the viewport width with the slider, or the display icons.

Comment: As i said, i've copied and paste a code of Bootstrap official website. My knowledge of Bootstrap and CSS is Basic. I really apreciate your help. I'll try and and Tell you If It works

Answer (score 2):

Start with a [simple Carousel from the Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#with-captions). The example you're using has various customizations which may be confusing if your "knowledge of Bootstrap and CSS is basic".